# scoped_allocator_adapter explanation in Stroustrup C++, is it Errata?

Tags: c++

I'm reading Stroustrup C++ 4th Ed Page 1001 on `scoped_allocator_adapter`. This text is from the book.  Does anyone know if the last comment `XXX` is correct?  From what I can tell, it looks wrong and vector is using My_alloc.

There is also some other typos in this section which makes me wonder if he is explaining `scoped_allocator_adapter` correctly here...  No mention in the [errata](https://www.stroustrup.com/4th_printing3.html), then again I have found multiple items at the end of this book not mentioned in this document either.

```
// vector and string use their own (the default) allocator:
using svec0 = vector<string>;
svec0 v0;

// vector (only) uses My_alloc and string uses its own allocator (the default):
using Svec1 = vector<string,My_alloc<string>>;
Svec1 v1 {My_alloc<string>{my_arena1}};

// vector and string use My_alloc (as above):
using Xstring = basic_string<char,char_traits<char>, My_alloc<char>>;
using Svec2 = vector<Xstring,scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<Xstring>>>;
Svec2 v2 {scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<Xstring>>{my_arena1}};

// XXX questioning this comment
// vector uses its own alloctor (the default) and string uses My_alloc:
using Xstring2 = basic_string<char, char_traits<char>, My_alloc<char>>;
using Svec3 = vector<xstring2,scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<xstring>,My_alloc<char>>>;
Svec3 v3 {scoped_allocator_adaptor<My_alloc<xstring2>,My_alloc<char>>{my_arena1}};
```

Comment: Seems like Xstring2 isn't used?

Comment: The book has a case issue with `Xstring2` and `xstring2`.  One errata, but I already know of that

Comment: On the `using Svec3` line, `xstring` is probably meant to be `Xstring2`.

Comment: @cdhowie That one is understood.  I'm concerned that the comment XXX is incorrect